# How do you interpret IO Busy in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Looking at Sybase symsmon files, I do see IO Busy to be very high 95%, most of the time. Can somebody explain what does this mean? Does IO Busy being too high impacts the performance of the DB? How can we address this so that IO Busy goes down?

Answer (score 1):

It means the ASE server is spending 95% of its cycles doing I/O. In principle, that's a good thing, since transactional applications are typically I/O-bound. However, if you have reason to believe that the amount of I/O is out of proportion with the workload, then you need to find out where that I/O is being spent. In other words: which queries are causing that I/O, what query plan do those queries have, and is that query plan optimal or not?
One starting point are the MDA tables; for example, use my proc sp_mda_io (download from http://www.sypron.nl/mda).

Comment: ASE spending 95% of its cycles to IO as opposed to what? Having a high IO busy, could cause latency, slowness? How do you recommend decreasing this by further portioning?

Comment: You need to determine if the query plans are optimal. If so, you just have a busy ASE server with a lot of workload, (or you have a slow disk). If they are not optimal (meaning: they are spending more I/O than reasonable for the query in question, then you need to look at optimizing the plan (for example, by adding indexes). There is no magic way to do this.